# How to get text from rich edit control as a CString

Tags: c++, mfc, rich-text-editor

I want to get the entire text in a rich edit control as a CString something like  GetDlgItemText but this is for dialog boxes. The closest thing i can find from my research is:
[GetTextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6tcchk5.aspx) and get the range by using [GetTextLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3a5w5wf.aspx)....But I suspect there is a better way....

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "better" but consider [EM_GETTEXTEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774192(v=vs.85).aspx) as an alternative.

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for replying. Would it be possible for you to provide an example of how to use EM_GETTEXTEX, or point me in the direction of one online? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- GetWindowText.
- GetDlgItemText works to, if you use the parent window and the ID of the RTF Control.
- WM_GETETXT.

If you want to retrieve the complete RTF text you Need to use EM_STREAMOUT (enough samples in the net).

Comment: how do you get the ID of the RTF Control?

Comment: ??? You just created it yourself, so you used the ID in CreateWindow or the Dialog template... look into the source code or the dialog template. If it is not your program, use Spy++...

Comment: also....i searched for CreateWindow....and the closest i got was a PreCreateWindow....but this did not use an ID.

Comment: And what settings for the program did you use? SDI/MDI. Is it a RTF-View. In the last case you find the Streaming in your document.

Comment: it is MDI and RTF-View.

Comment: Look into your document. AFAIK there is code that serializes the data. Please learn some basics!

Comment: There is no Need for the ID. YOu have the RTF control in the View. So you have the handle, it is justthe current View and you can use any other method that uses a window handle.